# AHK - stdout to variable working, but unable to use a variable inside comspec

Tags: autohotkey

I have stdout feeding to a variable when I use literal filepaths in my comspec line, but why can I not use a variable in place of the filename I want to be analyzed?

Note that mediainfo already (successfully) uses the % symbol in its own arguments. So how do I make comspec treat %LongPath% as a real variable?
I already tried adding an extra pair of quotes around %Longpath% as well, but no luck.

```
Loop %0%
{
Path := %A_Index%
Loop %Path%, 1
LongPath = %A_LoopFileLongPath%
SplitPath LongPath, OutFileName, OutDir, OutExtension, OutNameNoExt, OutDrive

objShell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
objExec := objShell.Exec(comspec " /c C:\MediaInfo.exe --Inform=Video;%FrameRate% %LongPath%")
framerate := ""
while, !objExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
 framerate := objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()

msgbox %framerate%
}
```

Thanks for some expertise.

Answer (score 0):

The key was the enclose the appname and arguments in quotes, (and make sure to leave an extra space before the last quote) and then not to include your final variable in the quotes.